# Finding the intersection of the Circle and Infinite Cylinder in 3D space

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

Finding the intersection of the Circle and Infinite Cylinder. (all in 3D)
•   Circle is defined by center, plane in which it lies and radius.
•   Cylinder is defined by axis and radius.

how can i get the intersection of these two?

Comment: maybe related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere%E2%80%93cylinder_intersection

Comment: but how to use it with cutting plane(which converts sphere to circle)..??

Comment: use an equation for a circle and do a similar analysis. it's probably easiest to fix the circle in the xy plane with center at the origin and let the cylinder be arbitrary.

Comment: maybe easier to fix cylinder on on z azis and use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492607/for-a-general-plane-what-is-the-parametric-equation-for-a-circle-laying-in-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLOG the cylinder has equation `X² + Y² = 1` (if not, you can make it so by translation, rotation and scaling).

Then the parametric equation of the circle is

```
P = C + U cos t + V sin t
```

where `C` is the center point and `U`, `V` two orthogonal vectors in the circle plane, of length `R`.

You can rationalize with the substitution `cos t = (1 - u²) / (1 + u²), sin t = 2u / (1 + u²)`.

Combining these equations,

```
(Cx (1 + u²) + Ux (1 - u²) + Vx 2u)² + (Cy (1 + u²) + Uy (1 - u²) + Vy 2u)² = (1 + u²)²
```

which is a quartic one. There is no particular simplification of the coefficients.

You can solve numerically or by the closed-form formulas. There can be up to four solutions.

---

I guess that this is strictly equivalent to finding the intersections between the torus formed by inflating the circle circumference and the straight line obtained by deflating the cylinder to its axis. This is well addressed in the ray-tracing literature.

You can also sse it as a circle/ellipse intersection problem in 2D.

Comment: @AmolN: what is it that you don't understand ? Why do you have to solve this problem ?

Comment: @AmolN: these are the simplest you can find.

Comment: @AmolN: the unknown is u, the coefficients are explained in the answer.

Comment: @AmolN: hem, isn't a circle planar?

Comment: bt Cylinder is a 3D object

Comment: @AmolN: when you look in the direction of the cylindre axis, you see a 2D problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's some base point of cylinder is A0, unit axis direction vector is AD, radius AR. Circle center is B0, circle plane unit normal is BN, radius BR.

Circle intersects cylinder, if distance from B0 to cyl. axis is smaller than sum of cylinder radius plus projection of circle radius onto normal to axis

```
Dist <= AR + BR * Abs(Cos(AD, BN)).

Cos(AD, BN) = DotProduct(AD, BN)
Distance(B0, cyl.axis) = Abs(VectorProduct(AD, B0-A0))
```